# Difference between "string matching" and "pattern matching"

Tags: bash, grep, pattern-matching, string-matching

**The fgrep command differs from the grep and egrep commands because it searches for a string instead of searching for a pattern that matches an expression.**

Can someone explain the difference in use with a simple example?

Comment: A pattern describes a whole set of strings in a single go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgrep` is equivalent to `grep -F` and `egrep` is equivalent to `grep -E`

`grep -F` matches strings and `grep -E` matches extended regular expression.

Given the input file:

```
$ cat file
Hello Alice!
Hello Bob!
Hi Alice!!
Hi Bob!!
```

Pattern matching:

```
$ grep -E -f <(echo -e "Ali.*\nBob") file
Hello Alice!
Hello Bob!
Hi Alice!!
Hi Bob!!
```

String matching:

```
$ grep -F -f <(echo -e "Ali.*\nBob") file
Hello Bob!
Hi Bob!!
```

In the second example, the `Ali.*` is not matching `Alice` because `grep` takes it as a litteral string.

I recommend having a look at [this page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17949/what-is-the-difference-between-grep-egrep-and-fgrep).